# error in my view function in Django 'decimal.Decimal' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms, python-requests

i have three models

```
# My models here.
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from django import forms
from django.urls import reverse
from configration.models import Site, Department, Category, Designation, Rate

class EmployeeRegistration(models.Model):
    #Departmental Details
    
    EmpId = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='EmpId')
    Site = models.ForeignKey(Site,on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=150,verbose_name='Site')
    Department = models.ForeignKey(Department,on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=150,verbose_name='Department')
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=150,verbose_name='Category')
    Designation = models.ForeignKey(Designation,on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=150,verbose_name='Designation')
    PfAllowance = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    EsiAllowance = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    Uan = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = True,verbose_name='Uan')
    Pf = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = True,verbose_name='Pf')
    Esic = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = True,verbose_name='Esic')
    AttendenceAward = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    AttendenceAllowance = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    ProfesionalTax = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Name')
    Father = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Father')
    Dob = models.DateField()
    Male = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    Female = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    MaritalStatus = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name='Address')
    Aadhar = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    pan = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    choices = [('Working','WORKING'),('NotWorking','NOT WORKING'),('Leave','Leave')]
    Status = models.CharField(choices=choices,blank = False,max_length=10,verbose_name='Status')
    Doj = models.DateField(default = date.today)
    Doe = models.DateField(blank = True,verbose_name = 'Doe',null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{name}'.format(name=self.Name)
  

class EmployeeRate(models.Model):
    EmpId = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='EmpId')
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name='Name')
    Site = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Site')
    Basic = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Basic')
    Da = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Da')
    Rate = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Rate')
    Hra = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Hra',null=True)
    Ca = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Ca',null=True)
    SplAllow = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='SplAllow',null=True)
    CanteenAllow = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='CanteenAllow',null=True)
    DateFrom = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{name}_{EmpId}'.format(name=self.Name,EmpId=self.EmpId)
`
class Rate(models.Model):
    Site = models.ForeignKey(Site,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=False)
    Department = models.ForeignKey(Department,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=False)
    Basic = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    Da = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    Rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    Hra = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    Ca = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    SplAllow = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    CanteenAllow = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    fromDate = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
        return '{site}_{cat}'.format(site =self.Site,cat=self.Category)
```

Please give some help or some hint why i am getting this error in my view function

```
def EmployeeRateView(request):
    msg = ''
    try:
        fromDate = request.POST.get('fromdate')
    except:
        msg = "Pleas enter valid date"


    if request.method == 'POST':
        RateData = EmployeeRate.objects.filter(Site=request.user.SuperVisor.Site,DateFrom=fromDate)
    return render(request,"employeerate.html",{"EmployeeRate":RateData,"msg":msg})
    else:
        print("get")
        rate = Rate.objects.filter(Site=request.user.SuperVisor.Site)
        EmpDetails = EmployeeRegistration.objects.filter(Site=request.user.SuperVisor.Site,Status="Working")
        for  employee in EmpDetails:
            for get in rate:
                print("date",get.fromDate)
                if(employee.Site==get.Site and employee.Category==get.Category and employee.Department==get.Department):
                    try:
                        check = EmployeeRate.objects.get(EmpId=employee.EmpId,DateFrom=get.fromDate)
                        print("found",check.EmpId,check.Name,get.fromDate)
                    except:
                        print("not found",check.EmpId,check.Name,get.fromDate)
                        rate = get.Basic+get.Da
                        print(rate)
                        print("basic",get.Basic,"da",get.Da,"rate",rate) 
                        EmployeeRate.objects.create(EmpId=employee.EmpId,
                                                    Name=employee.Name,
                                                    Site=employee.Site,
                                                    Basic=get.Basic,
                                                    Da=get.Da,Rate=rate,
                                                    Hra=get.Hra,
                                                    Ca=get.Ca,
                                                    SplAllow=get.SplAllow,
                                                    CanteenAllow=get.CanteenAllow,
                                                    DateFrom=get.fromDate)
               
          context = {'EmployeeRate':EmployeeRate.objects.filter(Site=request.user.SuperVisor.Site).order_by('Name'),'msg':msg}
    return render(request,"employeerate.html",context)
```

here is my template code

```
  {% if msg %}
        <p class="alert alert-warning">{{msg}}</p>
      {% endif %}
<div class="container" style=" padding: 0 !important; margin-top: 15px;background-color: #ffffff">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header bg-info">
    <i class="fas fa-book fa-3x" style="color:#ffffff"> EMPLOYEE RATE</i>
  </div>
<a href="{% url 'rate' %}" class="btn btn-warning" style="font-weight:900; color: whitesmoke;">Update Rate</a>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'rate' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="publishDateMax" name="fromdate">
          </div>
                            <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;">
                                Filter
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
<table class="table table-borderless table-hover" style="margin-left:10px !important;margin-right:10px !important;">
    <threed class="border-bottom font-weight-bold">
        <tr>
            <th>EmpId</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Basic</th>
            <th>Da</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Hra</th>
            <th>Ca</th>
            <th>SplAllow</th>
            <th>Canteen</th>
            <th>From Date</th>
        </tr>
        {% for ratedetails in EmployeeRate %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ratedetails.EmpId }}</td>
                <td>{{ ratedetails.Name }}</td>
                <td>{{ ratedetails.Basic }}</td>
                <td>{{ ratedetails.Da }}</td>
                <td>{{ ratedetails.Rate }}</td>
                <td>{{ ratedetails.Hra }}</td>
                <td>{{ ratedetails.Ca }}</td>
                <td>{{ ratedetails.SplAllow }}</td>
                <td>{{ ratedetails.CanteenAllow }}</td>
                <td>{{ ratedetails.DateFrom }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </threed>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my error in my terminal as well as in my browser
Basically i am trying to save or create some data in EmployeRate model based on filter and condition. But at the end it giving me this type of error. I can't able to understand why it is showing like this.

[image: error showing in browser]

Comment: Show us your template please.

Comment: Is there any other part of code where we can identify the decimal variable that are causing the problem ?

Comment: see my template code above.
 when i am using math function to change the decimal into integer like this 
```rate = math.floor(get.Basic)+math.floor(get.Da)``` then the error is this 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

Finally i overcome on this situation and found my solution.

Actually the problem was here

```
for  employee in EmpDetails:
            **for get in rate:** #looping in rate and initializing a variable by same name rate withing for loop of rate
                print("date",get.fromDate)
                if(employee.Site==get.Site and employee.Category==get.Category and employee.Department==get.Department):
                    try:
                        check = EmployeeRate.objects.get(EmpId=employee.EmpId,DateFrom=get.fromDate)
                        print("found",check.EmpId,check.Name,get.fromDate)
                    except:
                        print("not found",check.EmpId,check.Name,get.fromDate)
                        **rate = get.Basic+get.Da** # this was the actual error
                        print(rate)
                        print("basic",get.Basic,"da",get.Da,"rate",rate)
```